# Append array value to ID attribute of selected elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors, attributes

Simply, i'm trying to use jQuery to append a numeric value (currently stored in an array) to the end of the "id" attribute of a number of specified elements.

```
$('#headerAfirstLink, #headerAsecondLink, #headerAthirdLink, #headerAfourthLink').attr("id", // Append modCount[0].toString() to each existing ID);
```

The struggle I am having is in working out how to append the numeric value as opposed to simply set the ID equal to the numeric value. I don't want to lose the existing ID.

In the example, the preferred resulting ID's should be:

```
#headerAfirstLink1, #headerAsecondLink1, #headerAthirdLink1, #headerAfourthLink1
```

> *(If modCount[0] == 1).*

I'm sure it is crucifyingly simple but would appreciate some guidance.
Thanks

Comment: Can you add HTML too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`.attr(attributeName, function)`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/#attr-attributeName-function) syntax to update the attribute value for each of the respective element.

```
$('#headerAfirstLink, #headerAsecondLink, #headerAthirdLink, #headerAfourthLink')
    .attr("id", function(index, oldId) {
        // oldId is the attribute value
        return oldId + modCount[0];
    });
```

---

Just in case, to update the attribute of all the elements whose ID starts with `header`, you can use [attribute starts with selector](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/).

```
$('[id^="header"]').attr('id', function(index, oldId) {
    return oldId + modCount[0];
});
```

Comment: Brilliant, works as expected. However, I don't quite understand how oldId gets populated with the current ID. Does jQuery automagically pass the existing attribute name into the callback function?

Comment: @JordanDolan That code is same as `each`. Iterating over each of the matched element and pass the ID as second parameter to the `attr` callback function.

Answer (score 3):

Try to use [`.attr("attrName" , callBack)`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/#attr-attributeName-function) signature to achieve what you want.

```
$('#headerAfirstLink, #headerAsecondLink, #headerAthirdLink, #headerAfourthLink')
  .attr("id", function(_,id){
     return id +  modCount[0];
  });
```

Don't confuse the first parameter passed with callBack. It is index. I just used an underscore there as it is not required in our case. Simply to hide its visual.

Or the best/maintainable approach would be setting a common class (ex: test)  to those four elements and use a [`class selector`](https://api.jquery.com/class-selector/) there instead of [`multiple selector`](https://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/).

```
$('.test').attr('id', function(_, id) {
    return id + modCount[0];
});
```